# Vector functions - 2 functions meeting, sharing t value

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-bundles

I need to find out if these vector functions meet eachother at some point, where they share the same t value.
And if they do, i need the x/y values of where they meet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

The t variables can be set as one wishes, tm and tr that is.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the points of intersection of two plane parametric curves ?

Comment: I want to find out if the 2 functions meet in therms of X/Y position, while having the same t value. I can observe that they do meet by the mathcad sketch, but i do not know if they share t value when that happens

Comment: Yes, the points of intersection

Comment: Solve (by a numerical method) $\,x_m(t)=x_r(t)\,$ and $\,y_m(t)=y_r(t)$. Are there roots in common ?

Answer (score 0):

The system of equations 
$$\begin{split} 2t&= 2\cos t \\ \frac{6}{t+4}&=2\sin t \end{split}$$ 
has no solutions. Indeed, by squaring the equations and adding them, we see that a solution would satisfy 
$$t^2+\frac{9}{(t+4)^2}=1\tag{1}$$ which is an algebraic equation. On the other hand, $t=\cos t$ is transcendental equation; its only root is not an algebraic number.

Okay, I don't actually know a proof of the preceding claim, but it's easy enough to check that neither of two real roots of (1) satisfies $\cos t=t$. One of them is $\approx -0.51$, which obviously fails. The other, $\approx 0.78$, comes close, but its cosine is about $0.71$.